# JMeter http2 request timeout

Tags: jmeter, timeout, http2

While sending a get http2 request in JMeter I get java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Im trying to test http2 on out webportal, some get requests work fine, but some do not and I get `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1957)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2092)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.awaitResponses(HTTP2Connection.java:179)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:211)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:139)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:115)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)`

My configuration is : 
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
JMeter 5.1.1 + HTTP/2 Sampler plugin version: 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout for HTTP/2 sampler and check if it solves the problem.
[image]
Put 5 seconds if work decrease else try to increase it by 5.

Hope this helps.